# Allow certain number of users to connect to server [JAVA]

Tags: java, sockets, server

Alright, so I changed it to this, I closed the socket and modified the loop

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            connectedClients++;
            if (connectedClients < maxPlayers) {MortgageRunnable m = new MortgageRunnable(clientSocket);
                System.out.println("New player has connected!");
                new Thread(m).start();}
            else{out.println("Connection unsuccessful, Max players connected");clientSocket.close();}
```

the only thing left is it doesn't send the message to the client ("Connection unsuccessful, Max players connected") it just disconnects.
How can I send the message to the client?

Comment: "but its still not working"- what's wrong?

Comment: Where do you decrement the counter?

Comment: What's wrong is it doesn't stop clients from connecting after 2 are already connected.. It keeps accepting connections.

Comment: I don't decrement the counter because I don't need to. It starts at 0 and increments each time a client connects

Comment: Accept the connection, then close the connection if there are more than allowed.

Comment: miss break; when (connectedClients == maxPlayers)

Answer (score 0):

Your code continues to accept new incoming connections because the `while` loop does not exit. To fix that, once you hit the maximum allowed connections, you need to get out of the `while` loop. Here is your code (without the dangling `try` statement) with one extra line after printing "Max players connected". Once you reach `maxPlayers` total number of connections, this will stop accepting new connections.

```
while (true) {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    MortgageRunnable m = new MortgageRunnable(clientSocket);
    System.out.println("New player has connected!");
    if (!(connectedClients == maxPlayers)) {
        new Thread(m).start();
        connectedClients++;
    } else {
        m.displayMessage("Max players connected");
        break; // get out of the while loop
    }
}
```

Another small suggestion: instead of checking `if (!(connectedClients == maxPlayers) {...}`, change it to something like `if (connectedClients < maxPlayers) {...}` – simpler logic, the code is more readable, easier to reason about.

EDIT: here's a variation. This time, I've moved most of the work into a new `acceptNewClient()` method. Also, the `if` statement is reworked to eject once `connectedClients < maxClients` is no longer true.

```
public void listenForClientConnections() {
    while (true) {
        MortgageRunnable m = acceptNewClient();
        connectedClients++;

        boolean maxClientsReached = !(connectedClients < maxClients);
        if (maxClientsReached) {
            m.displayMessage("Max clients connected");
            break; // exit "while" loop, no more connections will be accepted
        }
    }
}

private MortgageRunnable acceptNewClient() {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    MortgageRunnable m = new MortgageRunnable(clientSocket);
    System.out.println("New client has connected!");
    new Thread(m).start();
    return m;
}
```

Comment: He also needs to fix the socket leak.

Comment: Good point. The loop should be rewritten to: accept new connection and start thread, then check total connection count and break from the whole loop if it matches max allowed.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a cleaner example.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be leaving sockets open when rejecting players.

The logic should be:

```
   while (true) {
       socket = accept()
       if (too many players)  {
           send "too many players" message
           close socket
       } else {
           increment player counter
           new Thread(new MortgageRunnable(socket)).start()
       }
    }
```

Also, when a player leaves / thread exits, you should decrement the counter.

Finally, creating a new `PrintWriter` each time you send a message is a bad idea.